# JsonRest get values to feed grid header dynamicaly

Tags: dojo, grid

I am using a dojo grid which I need to populate with a JsonRest.

This is the code:

```
require 
    (
        [ 'dojo/_base/lang', 'dojox/grid/DataGrid', 'dojo/data/ObjectStore', 'dojo/store/JsonRest', 'dojo/dom', 'dojo/domReady!' ],
        function ( lang, DataGrid, ObjectStore, JsonRest, dom )
        {

            jsonr = new JsonRest
            (
                { target: 'carrierSlideListStrategiesByGroupOrCarrierAction.do?output=<%=Constants.OUTPUT_JSON%>' }

            );

            var layout =
            [
                [
                    { 'name': 'strategyname', 'field': 'strategyid', 'width': '23%', 'cellStyles': 'white-space: nowrap;', 'headerStyles': 'white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; text-align: center;' }              
                ]
            ];

            grid00 = new DataGrid 
            (
                {
                    store: store00 = new ObjectStore ( { objectStore: jsonr } ),
                    structure: layout,
                    rowSelector: '20px'
                }
            );

            grid00.placeAt ( 'grid00' );
            grid00.startup ();
            dojo.connect 
            (
                grid00, 
                "_onFetchComplete",
                function ()
                {
                    $ ( '#msg_home' ).empty ();
                    $ ( '#msg_home' ).html ( '<table><tr><td><bean:message key="bodycarrierslidebygrouporcarrier.query.businessnumbers.done00"/>' + '<b>' + grid00.rowCount + '</b>' + '<bean:message key="bodycarrierslidebygrouporcarrier.query.done01"/></td></tr></table>' );
                }
            );
        }
    );
```

The data collection I am getting is the following :

```
[{"strategyid":"1","strategyname":"AR","strategycompliantflag":"GROUP_STRATEGY_NA"},
{"strategyid":"0","strategyname":"Facilities","strategycompliantflag":"GROUP_STRATEGY_NA"},
{"strategyid":"1","strategyname":"Panel","strategycompliantflag":"GROUP_STRATEGY_NA"},
{"strategyid":"0","strategyname":"Agreem.","strategycompliantflag":"GROUP_STRATEGY_NA"}
```

--etc

My objective, which I don't seem to know how to achieve, is to put in the grid´s header the value of the field strategyname and in the row the value of the field strategyid, instead I am getting in the header only one column like this:

```
-------------
strategyname
-------------
1  
0  
1
```

and I would like to have

```
------ ------------- -------   ----
AR      Facilities     Panel    Agreem
------  ------------ --------  --------
1         0             1       0
```

To do that I thought that I could query the JsonRest in a loop through the data collection to form the structure that I need and pass it to the grid.
Could someone help me please?

Comment: Out of curiosity (and off topic) : are you using JQuery on top of dojo ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using dojo 1.7+, so you can start by getting rid of all the calls to the dojo global (dojo.connect, etc...) and replace it by its AMD equivalent.

For what you are trying to achieve, you have to do this in 2 steps :

First, do a call to your store to fetch the data, and create your layout with something like :

```
var layout = array.map(yourJsonStore.query(), function (item) {
    return {
        name: item.strategyname,
        field: "strategycomplyantflag" + "_" + item.strategyname
     }
});
```

Then, mold your data items to match the field names declared in the layout, and put them in a memoryStore.

Example :

```
var transformedMemStore = new Memory({
    data: array.map(yourJsonStore.query(), function (item) {
        var obj = {};
        obj["id"] = item.strategyid;
        obj["strategycomplyantflag_" + item.strategyname] = item.strategycompliantflag;
        return obj;
     })
 });
```

Finally, create your objectStore with the transformed store as the objectStore property and assign it to your grid. Full example here : http://jsfiddle.net/psoares/9MLT5/

P.S. : I replaced your JsonRestStore by the MemoryStore "memStore" in the fiddle...